# FBSDKLoginManager is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

In my application the login with facebook was working before, but in last facebook sdk update (testing in iOS 9.0), it's not working.

1) When the user tap login with Facebook, the SFSafariViewController is shown (although the Facebook app is installed, the behavior is that open the SVC by default ~ but ok, that's not a problem):

[image: SFSafariViewController screentshot]

2) Then from the screen above, when the user choose Login With Facebook App (from facebook page), it show an alert asking that facebook want to open Facebook app:

[image: Dialog confirmation to open facebook App]

3) When the user tap "Open" from the dialog. I don't know why but the callback of FBSDKLoginManager is getting called with FBSDKLoginResult cancelled (isCancelled property). And the following message appear in console:
FBSDKLog: **ERROR**:
 The SFSafariViewController's parent view controller was dismissed.
This can happen if you are triggering login from a UIAlertController. Instead, make sure your top most view controller will not be prematurely dismissed.

4) Anyway the user is moved to the Facebook Application, from there the user can tap "Ok" (in case already authorized)

Finally when the user tap "Ok", is return back to the app, but the callback is not called.

Note: I have setup all the LSApplicationQuerySchema for Facebook. Also the two methods of openURL:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue and couldn't find any solution yet...